# Получение учетных данных пользователя по электронной почте

Tags: django

Я создаю небольшое решение для восстановления учетных данных пользователя. Я решил попробовать сделать это с помощью своего алгоритма. Я запрашиваю почту пользователя и сравниваю ее с базой данных почтовых адресов. Если почта существует, я хочу отправить пользователю его учетные данные (логин и пароль). Я уже сделал прием и проверку почты, а также настроил отправку электронных писем на почтовые адреса. Но как получить доступ к учетным данным только с помощью почты, при том факте, что пользователь не вошел в систему, я не понимаю. Я знаю, что, возможно, мое решение, не очень правильное в плане безопасности, но очень интересно, и я действительно хочу понять, как это сделать.

Может быть, можно быстро войти в систему и получить данные оттуда, или можно обойтись без этого?

views.py

```
def recovery(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("/accounts/exit/")
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            email_form = UserRecoveryForm(request.POST)
            if email_form.is_valid():
                email = email_form.cleaned_data['email']
                try:
                    send_mail("Восстановление учетных данных.", "message", "from@gmail.com", [email], fail_silently=False)
                except BadHeaderError:
                    return HttpResponse('Ошибка в теме письма.')
                return render(request, 'registration/recovery_done.html')
        else:
            email_form = UserRecoveryForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/recovery.html', {'email_form': email_form})
```

На всякий случай forms.py

```
class UserRecoveryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Почта', help_text='На почту мы отправим дополнительную информация в случае необходимости')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if (not(email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).exists())):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Такой почты не существует.')
        return email
```